# function inside a constructor with a this.route isn't putting it in as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, constructor

```
 this.routeCoord = function () {
    let holding = ['KSFM', 'KPWM']
    let coord = [];
    let coords = [];
    if (Array.isArray(holding) == true) {
        for (let i = 0; i < tempRoute().length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < database.length; j++) {
                if (holding[i] === database[j].ident) {
                    coord = [(Number(database[j].coordinates[0])), (Number(database[j].coordinates[1]))];
                    coords.push(coord)
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(coords)

        return;
    } else { }
```

When I run this I get exactly what I want, two coordinates that correspond to the input array. But what I want, is instead of defining the array "holding" I have a this.route() which is the same exact array. But this is from a constructor, so it doesn't come in as an array.

Here is where I am getting that array from, basically its an airport OR a list of airports that are added, then is an airport is missing the first letter, it adds the missing K. Either way, this has been returning an array all along so I don't know why my this.routeCoord isn't receiving it as an array.

```js
let database = [];

function apcodes() {
    const url = "https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/airport-codes/airport-codes_json/data/9ca22195b4c64a562a0a8be8d133e700/airport-codes_json.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        database = data;
        for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
            database[i].coordinates = database[i].coordinates.split(',');
        }
        run();
    });
}
apcodes();
let temp = ['2020-08-08', 'N11682', 'KSFM', 'KSFM', 'KRKD KPSM', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3.0', '3.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '3.0', '161.70', '0', '0', '3', '3', '3', '0.0', '0.0', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '3.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'Wayne'];

function run() {
    console.log(flight.route())
}



let flight = new Flight(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4], temp[11]);


function Flight(Date, AircraftID, From, To, Route, TotalTime) {

    this.date = Date;
    this.aircraft = AircraftID;
    this.from = function () {
        if (From.length < 4) {
            return 'K' + From
        }
        else {
            return From
        }
    }
    this.to = function () {
        if (To.length < 4) {
            return 'K' + To
        }
        else {
            return To;
        }
    };
    this.route = function () {
        let routeArr = [];
        if (Route.length > 4) {
            Route = Route.split(' ');
            for (let i = 0; i < Route.length; i++) {
                if (Route[i].length < 4) {
                    Route[i] = 'K' + Route[i]
                }
                routeArr.push(Route[i])
            }

            return routeArr
        } else if (Route.length < 4) {
            return 'K' + Route;
        } else {
            return Route
        }
    };
    let tempRoute = this.route;
    this.time = TotalTime;
    this.toCoord = function () {
        for (let j = 0; j < database.length; j++) {
            if (this.to() === database[j].ident) {
                let coord = [(Number(database[j].coordinates[0])), (Number(database[j].coordinates[1]))];
                return coord;
            }
        }
    };
    this.fromCoord = function () {

        for (let j = 0; j < database.length; j++) {

            if (this.from() === database[j].ident) {
                return [(Number(database[j].coordinates[0])), (Number(database[j].coordinates[1]))];
            }
        }
    };

    this.routeCoord = function () {

        let coord = [];
        let coords = [];
        if (Array.isArray(this.route()) == true) {
            for (let i = 0; i < tempRoute().length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < database.length; j++) {
                    if (this.route()[i] === database[j].ident) {
                        coord = [(Number(database[j].coordinates[0])), (Number(database[j].coordinates[1]))];
                        coords.push(coord)
                    }
                }
            }

            return coords;
        } else {
            for (let j = 0; j < database.length; j++) {
                if (this.route() === database[j].ident) {
                    coord = [(Number(database[j].coordinates[0])), (Number(database[j].coordinates[1]))];
                }
            }
            return coord;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `But this is from a constructor, so it doesn't come in as an array` what do you mean "from a constructor"? What does it return? And maybe share the shape of your class with us so we can see how it fits together. In reduced form

Comment: {this.route = function () {
        let routeArr = [];
        if (Route.length > 4) {
            Route = Route.split(' ');
            for (let i = 0; i < Route.length; i++) {
                if (Route[i].length < 4) {
                    Route[i] = 'K' + Route[i]
                }
                routeArr.push(Route[i])
            }

            return routeArr
        } else if (Route.length < 4) {
            return 'K' + Route;
        } else {
            return Route
        }
    };
}

Comment: Maybe add that to your question? Click the `edit` link on the bottom of your question.

Comment: No worries. That code you just shared in the comments, how do you mean it's part of the constructor? I can see it being a function added to the `this` context but no constructor. I'm asking becuase I fear it might be out of scope for you to all in your `routeCoord` function. But I can't be sure

Comment: Maybe do this for now: `console.log(this.route())` between `let coords = [];` and `if (Array.isArray(this.route()) == true) {` and tell me what is being returned. There are a lot of side effects in your functions that make it hard to know what they return from here

Comment: For the `route` code you have shared, if `Route.length <= 4` it returns a string, not an array.

Comment: Sure! the return from this.route() is ['KSFM", "KRKD"] but the for loop is logging that array as induvidual characters for some reason

Comment: And add to what @Nick said: in your `else` clause it could return any type it was before which includes all types apart from an array

Comment: Do `let holding = this.route()` on the top of your `this.routeCoord` function and then replace all `this.route()` with `holding`.

Comment: wow.. Idk how but I thought I tried that but it worked! Thanks Dominik!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cache the function return so you have certainty that nothing has changed over the course of running your program. There are a lot of side effects in your code which would cause that.

```
this.routeCoord = function () {
  let holding = this.route();
  let coord = [];
  let coords = [];
  if (Array.isArray(holding) == true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tempRoute().length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < database.length; j++) {
        if (holding[i] === database[j].ident) {
          coord = [
            Number(database[j].coordinates[0]),
            Number(database[j].coordinates[1]),
          ];
          coords.push(coord);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(coords);

    return;
  } else { }
};
```